# Filter nested objects by property

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, rest

I am consuming a (badly designed) API which sends the following response:

```js
{
   "0" : {
      "name" : "John",
      "last_name" : "Doe"
   },
   "1" : {
      "name": "Mary",
      "last_name": "Ann"
   },
   [...]
}
```

As you may have noticed, it is a large JSON object with nested objects. Since it isn't an array, i can't use `.filter()`. So, how can i filter this large object by a nested object property (e.g. `name` or `last_name`)?

Comment: You can make it as array using `Object.values(type).flat()`. Then it will make the object values as single array.

Comment: Could you please provide an example? I'm not familiar with Javascript unfortunately

Comment: Is your expected output after the filter an array or object? Are the keys (ie: 0, 1, etc...) continuous like the indexes in an array, or can they have gaps in them (eg: you have keys 0, 3, but not the keys in between 1,2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it as array using Object.values(type).flat(). Then it will make the object values as single array.

```js
const input1 = {
   "0" : {
      "name" : "John",
      "last_name" : "Doe"
   },
   "1" : {
      "name": "Mary",
      "last_name": "Ann"
   }
}

function search(input, key) {
  return Object.values(input).flat().filter(({ name }) => name === key);
}

console.log(search(input1, "John"));
```